# iOS Push Notification internal corporate alternative - would it be necessary?

Tags: ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

for an corporate app (i.e. used by employees and communicating with corporate servers) is push notification a suitable approach given that it goes via the APNS?
I understand also that there can be no guarantee that the message is successfully received and that maybe it should be a notification that there is something ready to get.
If not are there any alternative approaches and if so what should I investigate?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an easy task but It is possible with push notification services. I, for example, use http://www.pushwoosh.com/ for my applications for iOS and Android. They offer a lot of helpful solutions for push notification for any mobile platforms. I hope this information can help you.